# Interpreting URL's liberally in Java

Tags: java, string, url, web

I have user input for a URL field.  I want them to be able to enter anything from "http://andrewducker.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php" to "andrewducker.wordpress.com" and be able to end up at the same end point.

I've wasted a couple of hours messing around with the various constructors for URL and not got to anywhere satisfactory, should I just do string checking and construct it myself?

(IF you're interested it's because I'm writing something which will post links from Delicious to Wordpress and I need the user to tell me their Wordpress URL so I can make an xmlrpc call to it.)

Edit: I should make it clear - I *always* want the /xmlrpc.php bit to be what's on the end of the URL, that's a Wordpress standard, so I don't need to do any complex discovery.  I just need to append that if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression matching to find out the host part. For example if you match against this regular expression "(https?://)?([^/\?]+)" the host is the second match group.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this.

Firstly you need to add "http://" in front of the URI if the scheme part is unspecified, e.g.

```
// We could do this with a regex, but its easier to use the built-in parser of the UIR class
URI uri = new URI(uriText);
if (uri.getScheme() == null) {
    uriText = "http://" + uriText;
    uri = new URI(uriText);
}
```

The second part is harder, because it involves a server redirect.  You cannot know this without making a connection to the server,
e.g. `"http://site1.com"` may be equivalent to `"http://www.site1.com/index.html"`
but `"http://site2.com"` may be equivalent to `"http://site2.com/en/default.aspx"`

Your best bet is probably to make a `HttpUrlConnection` and check for a 301 response and if you get one then use the URI from that.